# Function to count how many numbers in an array meet a certain condition

Tags: c, function, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to create a function that counts how many "dominant" numbers an array contains. By dominant I mean that a number is bigger than anything below to the right of itself. I created the main to test if it works but the program just crashes. Any suggestions?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define NR 4
    #define NC 8
    int dominants(int arr[NR][NC]);
    int main(int argc,const char *argv[]){
          int n;
          int array[NR][NC]={{5,9,2,4,1,7,2,4}
                            ,{3,5,6,2,5,6,1,2}
                            ,{1,3,4,7,8,8,3,0}
                            ,{1,3,5,6,7,8,2,1}};

          n=dominants(array);
          printf("there are %d dominants", n);
          return 0;
    }
    int dominants(int arr[NR][NC]){
        int i, j, k, l;
        int flag, num;
        num=0;
        flag=0;
        for(i=0;i<NC;i++){
            for(j=0;j<NR;j++){
                for(k=i+1;j<NC;k++){
                    for(l=k+1;l<NR;l++){
                        if(arr[j][i]<=arr[l][k]){
                            flag=1;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if(flag==1)
                num++;
        }


    return num;
    }
```

Comment: Yes: use a debugger to determine where it crashes and trace/print variables back from there.

Comment: Yes, in `k=i+1;j<NC;k++`, change `j` to `k`.

Comment: You should also obviously reset `flag` back to `0` at some point (probably immediately after incrementing `num`).

Comment: Finally, in all but the most outer `for` loop, you may as well add `&& flag == 0` in the loop condition.

Comment: thank you  @goodvibration but i don't undertang why the && flag==0, is it just for efficency reason or is there something else?

Comment: Yes, efficiency. That what I wrote 'you may'.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 24 as condition there is j<NC whereas it should be k<NC: "for(k=i+1;j<NC;k++){" to "for(k=i+1;k<NC;k++){"